# Unable to get migrate exchange mailboxes due to unknown status of MRS proxy

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook, imap, microsoft-office-365

We have decided to make the change to Office365 and migrate all our e-mails.

Office 365 needs the MRS proxy role to be active in order for the migration to complete.

Form that is prompting us for FQDN of MRS proxy:

[image: Picture of form that is prompting us for FQDN of MRS proxy]

We decided to do an IMAP Exchange instead (as we cant figure out the status of the MRS proxy) to our 365 service. This successfully migrated our e-mails but did not migrate contacts, calendars, to-do lists etc. We tried exporting .PST files of these contacts, calendars, to-do's and re-importing them into their Outlook folders.

This sadly did not work as they would get "(This computer only)" on the imported items; It would not sync with the 365 server. This wont work for staff, they need their stuff on the server as most of them use different computers (home/work) and mobile devices. I even tried uploading the individual .PST files to O365 but as I found out from Microsoft Support, that method only migrates e-mails.

Is there any way anyone has tried to get all of our e-mails, contacts, calendars, to-do lists, everything on to the 365 server?

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. This isn't the place to complain about your service provider. I did my best to clean it up to make it a readable, objective question. Please keep this in mind for future questions (and feel free to edit your question further to make it clearer - just leave out the subjective stuff).

Answer (score 0):

MRS proxy definitely needs to be enabled for Exchange web services, on the local Exchange server.  The EWS endpoint also must be publicly accessible, and you must be using a public certificate to secure the endpoint.  If Office 365 doesn't trust the cert, it will fail to connect.  As far as I know it only connects over HTTPS.

Also use the connectivity analyzer to validate your local installation.  If you can run the EWS tests successfully, it should work from Office 365.

For native moves, Hybrid, Staged, or cutover migrations - all using MRS proxy are the only ways to really get your data over without issue.  If you don't want to use native tools, you can look at something like MigrationWiz to help you.  However, neither method will work for you if your Exchange environment is not healthy or your have set up your endpoints correctly.